# How can I make this tkinter output look tidier?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have created this code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import ast
root=Tk()
root.title( "The following Motherboards and Daughterboards are not on the deck.")
root.grid()
root.configure(background="ghost white")

def KillWindow():
    root.destroy()

with open(r"G:MissingItems.txt","r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        plates = [int(i) for i in ast.literal_eval(line.strip())]
        print(plates)

NoMissing = len(plates)
print (NoMissing)

labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = "These Motherboards are missing!!!", font = ("Arial", 24, "bold"),)
labelwidget.grid(column = 1)

if NoMissing > 0:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [0], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 1, column = 0,)
if NoMissing > 1:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [1], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
if NoMissing > 2:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [2], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
if NoMissing > 3:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [3], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 2, column = 0)
if NoMissing > 4:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [4], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 2, column = 1)
if NoMissing > 5:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [5], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 2, column = 2)
if NoMissing > 6:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [6], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 3, column = 0)
if NoMissing > 7:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [7], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 3, column = 1)
if NoMissing > 8:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [8], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 3, column = 2)
if NoMissing > 9:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [9], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 4, column = 0)
if NoMissing > 10:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [10], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 4, column = 1)
if NoMissing > 11:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [11], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 4, column = 2)
if NoMissing > 12:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [12], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 5, column = 0)
if NoMissing > 13:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [13], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 5, column = 1)
if NoMissing > 14:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [14], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 5, column = 2)
if NoMissing > 15:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [15], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 6, column = 0)
if NoMissing > 16:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [16], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 6, column = 1)
if NoMissing > 17:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [17], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 6, column = 2)
if NoMissing > 18:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [18], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 7, column = 0)
if NoMissing > 19:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [19], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 7, column = 1)
if NoMissing > 20:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [20], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 7, column = 2)
if NoMissing > 21:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [21], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 8, column = 0)
if NoMissing > 22:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [22], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 8, column = 1)
if NoMissing > 23:
    labelwidget=Button(root, bg=("forest green"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = plates [23], font = ("Arial", 16, "bold"),)
    labelwidget.grid( row = 8, column = 2)

labelwidget2=Button(root, bg=("red"), fg=("white smoke"), relief=("raised"), text = "Cancel", font = ("Arial", 24, "bold"), command = KillWindow)
labelwidget2.grid(row = 9, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

which reads from a text file containing up to 24 bar code Ids in the following format

```
[3000000.0, 5000000.0, 6000000.0, 7000000.0, 8000000.0, 1234567.0, 1234568.0, 9876543.0, 3000001.0, 5000001.0, 6000001.0, 7000001.0, 8000001.0, 1234561.0, 1234561.0, 9876541.0, 6000002.0, 7000002.0, 8000002.0, 1234562.0, 1234562.0, 9876542.0,9876543.0,9876544.0]
```

The output is a bit ugly.

[image]

Any ideas on how I could make this tidier and more appealing on the eyes?

Maybe make it so the cancel button and the 'The Motherboards are missing!!!' button are as wide as the three columns of bar code Ids and the columns are touching.

Comment: You may want to head over to https://ux.stackexchange.com/. They answer questions about creating appealing user interfaces. You can also clean up your button creation by putting it in a for-loop. `for mobo_ix in range(NoMissing): row=mobo_ix // 3; col = mobo_ix % 3`. You can use `row` and `col` for your call to grid. Note that this way, you only have to write the button creation code *once* instead of *23* times. The `3` is the max number of collumns you want to have

Comment: Thank you. I instinctively knew to write the button so many times was wrong but I was clueless as to how to do it without  I have managed to play about with the code you suggested and I have managed to get it to work. I knew I would have to change the 'text =' in the code for the button, but it took me a few minutes to deduce it should be 'text = mobo_ix'. I do not understand why your code works. I need to get my head around the use of // and %. A search tells me they are Floor division and modulus. I will check out the website too. Thank you.

Comment: `//` is integer division. It takes the result and just chops off the decimal part. Ex: `2.9 // 1` evaluates `2.9/1` then truncates the result to an integer, or `2` in this case. `%` is modulus. `a % b` returns the remainder of `a/b`. Using `a // b` to find the row is nice because it will only increment by 1 every time `a` reaches a new multiple of `b`. And then `a % b` for cols is nice because it will always increment by 1, but will never exceed `b`. This means you keep your row constant while you fill out the columns. Then it increments the row and starts the columns over

Comment: You can use `mobo_ix` to index into your `plates` array and extract the motherboard ID or whatever that number is. ie, in your loop you do `text = plates[mobo_ix]`